# How do you add additional rows from multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, excel

My DF looks like this:

```
ID  V1    V2  V3
A   100  200    
B   100     
C   300     
D   400     
E   223  233   4
```

I want to transform it in R, such that the multiple 'V' columns come under one another with repeating IDs:

```
ID  V1
A   100
A   200
B   100
C   300
D   400
E   223
E   233
E   4
```

What is the best way of doing this in R or Excel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping time series data from wide to tall format (for plotting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060/reshaping-time-series-data-from-wide-to-tall-format-for-plotting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(melt(setDT(df), id.var="ID", na.rm=TRUE)[order(ID), -2, with = FALSE], 2, "V1")[]
#   ID  V1
#1:  A 100
#2:  A 200
#3:  B 100
#4:  C 300
#5:  D 400
#6:  E 223
#7:  E 233
#8:  E   4
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% gather(new, V1, 2:4) %>% filter(!is.na(V1))
```

If you don't want the "new" column add this cody (library "dplyr"):

```
%>% select(id, V1)
```

Comment: gather also has `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: I tried doing this, got an error:   Error in filter(., !is.na(V1)) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: It should work. Here you have analogical solution with chracter data: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045301/removing-incomplete-cases-from-output-of-tidyr-gather-r)